# binding to static property problem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm using the `EntityFramework` and working on an invoicing application. Below is the xaml code from my`DataGrid`. Now it compiles and everything works great, but the problem is, the static binding I have on the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` throws an exception when in designer mode because that static property actually loads from a `MySql` database using the entity framework.

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="ItemsGrid" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" FontSize="11" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" GridLinesVisibility="None" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="150" Header="Item No.">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBox Width="130" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Text="{Binding Number}" />
                            <Image MouseDown="ItemSelectionButton_Click" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="12" Source="/Images/Icons/SearchBlack.png" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="70" Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding Quantity}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="70" Header="Order" Binding="{Binding Order}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="70" Header="B/O" Binding="{Binding BackOrder}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="60" Header="Units" Binding="{Binding Units}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="90" Header="Price" Binding="{Binding Price}" />
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="50" Header="Tax" ItemsSource="{x:Static app:Session.TaxCodes}" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding TaxCodeID}" DisplayMemberPath="Code" SelectedValuePath="ID" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="90" Header="Amount" Binding="{Binding Amount}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="90" Header="Linked" Binding="{Binding SalesOrderID}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Here's the exception:

```
The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateEntityConnection(String connectionString)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(String connectionString, String defaultContainerName)
   at DtcInvoicer.Models.DatabaseEntities..ctor() in F:\Development\DTC Industrial\DtcInvoicer\DtcInvoicer\Models\DatabaseModel.Designer.cs:line 42
   at DtcInvoicer.Models.Repository.get_GetContext() in F:\Development\DTC Industrial\DtcInvoicer\DtcInvoicer\Models\Repository.cs:line 14
   at DtcInvoicer.Models.TaxCodesRepository.SelectAll() in F:\Development\DTC Industrial\DtcInvoicer\DtcInvoicer\Models\TaxCodesRepository.cs:line 54
   at DtcInvoicer.Session..cctor() in F:\Development\DTC Industrial\DtcInvoicer\DtcInvoicer\Session.cs:line 18
```

I know trying to fix the root of the problem will be too much work, I'm wondering if there's a simple workaround like dynamically binding to a static property in another class. Anyone have any idea how to do this? Looking for a `xaml` only solution.

Here's what I already tried...

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TaxCodes, Source={x:Static app:Session}}"

ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TaxCodes, Source={StaticResource app:Session}}"

ItemsSource="{Binding app:Session.TaxCodes}"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use something like `d:ItemsSource="{x:Null}"`, and define `d` in your Window or UserControl like `mc:Ignorable="d"`?

It should make the design-time property of `ItemsSource` equal to `null`

**Edit**

Forgot to add the definition for `mc` - It is 
             `xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"`

Comment: Hey Rachel, I got it to work. I just had to specify the full path to the member in my x:Static block `{Binding Source={x:Static app:Session.TaxCodes}}`. I tried your approach first, but could no get it to work, I wasn't aware I could do something like that so I'm interested in learning. What I tried was adding two properties on the column, `d:ItemsSource="{x:Null}"` and `ItemsSource="{my binding...}"` But it said I'm defining the property more than once. And the ignorable part said that I have to define the namespace d, what namespace would that be? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Saad Imran Sorry, I forgot to add the namespace for `mc`. Add the `mc` and `d` namespace to your class and it should work. I honestly don't use the designer that much, but adding `mc` and `d` is what Expression Blend uses to determine if it's in Design Time or Run Time, so I think it should work. I haven't tested it though :)

Comment: Ahh got it. Thanks a lot!. Learned something new today :)